# SharePoint application page - why try-catch doesn't work?

Tags: sharepoint, error-handling

My application page doesn't work correctly. In error log I could find this:

```
Detected use of SPRequest for previously closed SPWeb object.  Please close SPWeb objects when you are done with all objects obtained from them, but not before.
```

In my application page in code behind I have all snippets of code in try-catch blocks.
The question is why when such situation(described in log) appears the control doesn't go to catch statment?  Instead of that the internal SharePoint error appears on screen.

Regards

Comment: SharePoint's objects that use SPRequest are funny buggers when you have try catch-finally, especially if you're picking up the SPRequest from a current context, or you've lost track of your objects. Please paste a sample of code for us to look at and I can probably tell you in seconds what's going wrong.

Comment: The problem is I have houndred of lines and no idea where such situation appears..

Comment: Search keywords "Using" and "Dispose". You must have disposed an object you should not. You can also try this tool : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck

Comment: @Goglue: if he's manually called Dispose on an object, then tried to reuse it, I'm not sure if SPDisposeCheck will pick up on that... (2 mins, I'll test) - EDIT: Confirmed. If you Call SPWeb.Dispose() then do something like get the SPWeb.Title, then DisposeCheck doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @Chris: How have you developed your application page? Written those hundreds of lines of code then hoped it worked? It must have worked up to a certain point, a particular method for example, might've broken it.

Comment: What actually doesn't work correctly? What is the unexpected behavior? Track the issue based on that.

Comment: @Goglue: Thanks for the tool - I will try it soon. @JamesLove, @NLV: Also thanks for response. Output of my application is a report generated in a context of a certain SharePoint site and it works in almost all cases. But I have one SharePoint site which causes such problem. Worse, I have very restricted access to this site, I mean I have no oppurtunity to develop some tests based on method deleting, etc.

Comment: I bet you have a catch somewhere in which you're trying to access a Disposed SPWeb or SPSite object.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not going to your catch block is because the message being logged is just a warning, it doesn't interrupt the execution of your code.

[Use SPDisposeCheck to pinpoint the origin of the message.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck)

Comment: If the error message is accurate (this is SharePoint, so probably not) then it's saying there's an attempted use of a previously Disposed SPWeb object - which SPDisposeCheck doesn't pick up on (I think it inspects the Garbage Collector to see what's due for disposal by .NET, and kicks and screams if it sees a SharePoint object in there).

Comment: It is SharePoint, so nothing surprises me any more :-)